# VLOOKUP to merge two tables into one

Tags: excel

I have 2 price lists from 2 different companies but there are some many similar item numbers, is there a code to merge the pricelists into one? below example of what I have.

## A-Pricelist

- Item | Product | Price
- 382101 | Truck | 130$
- 212012 | car | 80$

## B-Pricelist

- Item | Product | Price
- 111011 | Airplane | 500$
- 382101 | truck | 50$

## Expected result

- Item | Product | A Price | B Price
- 382101 | Truck | 50$ | 130$
- 212012 | car | 80$ | -
- 111011 | Airplane |  - |500$

I have seen it is done by Vlookup, but it is just not working for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, vlookup will work fine, I would think about how to control the list of unique values using a dropdown...

But here is an example, updated to deal with missing prices:
[image]